# Split string into two parts of same size by words only in java/android

Tags: java, android, string, substring

how to split one string into two parts of same size but not between word ? 
i want to split one string into two same size parts but string should not be split between words but it only be spit between white spaces only.

Comment: Same size in terms of words? Or characters?

Comment: characters means length.. but need it almost same

Comment: @PhilippJahoda What was wrong in your answer, other than cutting away the spaces? It's the only issue I can spot. I'd use a variable for this: `yourstring.length() / 2)` in order to minimize math ops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Determine length of the word
2. Determine the middle
3. Search from the middle the next whitespace in both directions
4. Take the Whitespace with the lower distance to the middle and create two substrings

Comment: +1 but I'm sure that he wants a code ready to copy&paste :) anyway such problems were typical excerices on basic programming lessons in **primary school**

Answer (score 0):

For Split String with odd Length and even Length I use below Code and I answered.

```
String st= (String) st.getText().toString().trim();
              int length = st.length();
                boolean flag = length%2==0?true:false;
                String[] splits = new String[2];
                if(flag){
                    splits[0] = st.substring(0, length/2);
                    splits[1] = st.substring(length/2, length);
                }else{
                    int middle = length/2;
                    splits[0] = st.substring(0, middle);
                    splits[1] = st.substring(middle, length);
                }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
        String s = "123456789";
        int length = s.length();
        boolean flag = length%2==0?true:false;
        String[] splits = new String[2];
        if(flag){
            splits[0] = s.substring(0, length/2);
            splits[1] = s.substring(length/2, length);
        }else{
            System.out.println("cannot split this string into two same size parts,because its length is not even");
        }
        System.out.println(splits[0]);
        System.out.println(splits[1]);
```